# We do we consider VCE in the equations?

Tags: voltage, transistors, current

[image]

[image]

Like, this example didn't consider VCE in the equation at all. Why is that?

Comment: The picture doesn't match the formulas so anything can happen in reality. Also, you give no context and no linkage to where this came from. Do you really expect an answer on that basis?

Comment: @Andyaka Why they don't match? I don't get it.

Comment: @Andyaka They are from here: https://effectpedalkits.com/blog/electronics-tutorials-the-bjt-transistor-ii/

Comment: If you look at the diagram, can you unambiguously state what Vcc is?

Comment: Use a reputable site for this and not one aimed at guitarists.

Comment: @Andyaka I really don't know about all this though, I just want to know if I have to put VCE always.

Comment: Yes, 3b should include VCE. This is a rubbish tutorial.

Comment: There are several errors in that tutorial.  I wouldn't try to learn electronic theory from that.

Comment: In loop1 you have (without intention?) set VCE=0. And now you are asking us WHY it does nort appear?

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis I wasn't trying to learn electronic from that website. I just wanted to find an example for my situation and I searched for it in Google and I found it on that website, that's all.

Answer (score 2):

> Like, this example didn't consider VCE in the equation at all. Why is that?

Equations 3b is **wrong**, \$V_{CE}\$ should be included.

Equation 3b should have been:

\$V_{CC}=I_C*R_C + V_{CE} + I_E * R_E\$

Equation 3a is correct and includes \$V_{BE}\$ like it should.